# Donations through iPhone Application

Tags: ios, payment

I am developing an App where user can make donations from the App. I read about the Apple guidelines which state the following

> 21.Charities and contributions
>
> 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
>
> 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

I am going with the first option. Now, my question here is what does Apple mean by saying "**recognized charitable organizations**". How do they distinguish the organizations.

Comment: In most countries charities have to be registered with a government agency in order to get charitable status in law and for tax purposes. E.g. in the UK a registered charity has a unique registration number. If a charity doesn't have a valid registration number then it's not a legal charity. This isn't a programming question though, so voting to close.

Comment: What do you mean, "going with the first option"? You need both 21.1 and 21.2 to be compliant.

Comment: Likewise in the US, a "recognized charitable organization" would be a 501(c)(3). And, if you're not a recognized charitable organization, you wouldn't represent yourself as such. What kind of organization are you representing?

Comment: @Pork I assume he was talking web v SMS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for other countries, but in Canada **Charitable Organizations** need to be registered to accept donations and provided tax return statements.

Check out the footer of http://www.oxfam.ca for example:

> Charitable Registration: #12971 6866 RR0001

They registered to http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/chrts-gvng/lstngs/menu-eng.html. I'm pretty certain that Apple will require a registration from a government agency. You should research the laws applying to your country.